# HTML and CSS refactoring according to BEM methodology

Tags: html, css, bem

I'd like to refactor existing code and implement BEM naming convention.

But I am facing difficulties in converting code into markup that fits BEM conventions/requirements,
especially with nested elements.

I'm looking for the answers to the following question:

1. What is proper way of naming nested elements in BEM methodology?
2. How should I name elements to make it scale in modification/nesting and keep it reusable?

**Existing code:** (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karltynan/msavvhp9/)

```
<header class="lHeader">
  <div class="lHeaderInner clearfix">
    <h1 class="lHeaderLogo"><a class="link" href="/">Site Name</a></h1>

    <nav class="lNav">
      <div class="lNavInner clearfix">
        <h1 class="lNavTitle">Menu</h1>
        <div class="lNavContent">
          <ul class="list clearfix">
            <li class="level1 home"><a class="link" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="level1"><a class="link" href="/about/">About</a></li>
            <li class="level1 login alt"><a class="link" href="/about/">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="lSocial account">
      <div class="lSocialInner clearfix">
        <ul class="list clearfix">
          <li class="level1 twitter"><a class="link" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="level1 facebook"><a class="link" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="level1 googlePlus"><a class="link" href="#">Google+</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

**Attempted code:** (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karltynan/hd7r0n3a/)

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__inner clearfix">
    <h1 class="logo"><a class="link" href="/">Site Name</a></h1>

    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="nav__inner clearfix">
        <h1 class="nav__title">Menu</h1>
        <div class="nav__content">
          <ul class="menu clearfix">
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--home"><a class="link" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="link" href="/about/">About</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--login menu__item--alt"><a class="link" href="/about/">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="social account">
      <div class="social_inner clearfix">
        <ul class="menu clearfix">
          <li class="menu__item menu__item--twitter"><a class="link" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="menu__item menu__item--facebook"><a class="link" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="menu__item menu__item--googlePlus"><a class="link" href="#">Google+</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: http://cssguidelin.es/#bem-like-naming

Comment: Cheers Steve! Do you use it (or similar)? I am getting confused with items that are deeper in blocks, so lists within blocks (which don't really get used elsewhere).

Comment: Karl, your attempted code looks quite reasonable.

Comment: Yes - been dabbling, but only on a couple of projects so far. It feels very verbose which takes a bit of getting used to. I think your example looks good - perhaps with the exception of the .link class. I'd be inclined to use menu__item__link for that class I think.

Comment: My concern is the duplication of menu everywhere, and that it may need overriding in each case?

Comment: have you checked out this - http://bem.info/method/definitions/ ?

Comment: While I think this is an interesting discussion (and I do think your attempt looks neat), this is very opinion-based and as such probably not a good question for SO.

Comment: @StephanMuller, cant agree with you. BEM has strict defined naming convention, there is no place for opinion based answers.

Comment: @Evgeniy yes, which is fine if you only have one level of HTML, but what if you have a menu inside a menu with variations? And you want to reuse the menu somewhere else but it looks completely different? And I do agree that this can be asked as BEM is strict and there is only a certain way of achieving it...

Comment: This question is not opinion based, as I believe there are restrictive guidelines using BEM.

Comment: @KarlTynan, Absolutely agree, may be few variations, but they should be very close to each other. It does not really matter how nested you code. To get the idea of BEM, expect menu as `BLOCK` and menu item as `ELEMENT` .You can simply add new menu block inside parent block element. In case you need modifications you have to use `MODIFIERS`, modifiers may be applied to blocks and elements as well. Plus - very important tool - mixin - you can add some class from parent block to child block or its element. Looks a bit knotty, but fill free to ping in if need future assistance.

Answer (score 1):

With an alternative BEM syntax:

```
<header class="Header">
  <div class="Header-inner ob-clearfix">
    <h1 class="Header-logo"><a class="ob-link" href="/">Site Name</a></h1>

    <nav class="Header-nav Nav">
      <div class="Nav-inner ob-clearfix">
        <h1 class="Nav-title">Menu</h1>
        <div class="Nav-content">
          <ul class="Menu ob-clearfix">
            <li class="Menu-li level1 home"><a class="ob-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="Menu-li level1"><a class="ob-link" href="/about/">About</a></li>
            <li class="Menu-li level1 login alt"><a class="ob-link" href="/about/">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="Header-social Social">
      <div class="Social-inner ob-clearfix">
        <ul class="Menu ob-clearfix">
          <li class="Menu-li level1 twitter"><a class="ob-link" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="Menu-li level1 facebook"><a class="ob-link" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="Menu-li level1 googlePlus"><a class="ob-link" href="#">Google+</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I described this syntax in [an article in french](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1641-bonnes-pratiques-en-css-bem-et-oocss.html#une-syntaxe-bem-jolie):

- ComponentName
- ComponentName.modifierName
- ComponentName-descendantName
- ComponentName-descendantName.modifierName

The components are blocks and descendants are elements.

The classes "Header-nav" and "Header-social" should serve to position "Nav" and "Social" in the "Header".

A note about the "ob-clearfix": The modifiers should not be styled independently of their component because it does not conform to the BEM methodology. So, for transversal classes like OOCSS objects, here is the syntax I use:

- myPrefix-...